# Http.HttpRequestException to vagrant host

Tags: c#, rest, vagrant, httpresponsemessage

I have REST API server on my vagrant machine. And I write client for it on c# (VS2015).

**Have same code:**

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_server);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    try
    {
         response = await client.GetAsync(_action);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

**Trouble:**

Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
An error occurred while sending the request.

If I send request to another (non-vagrant) host, all is OK.

**Question:** *How I can solve this?*

Thanks)

**UPDATED**

***Stack trace***

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
mess: An error occurred while sending the request.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Uborka.Models.ApiModel.<_Response>d__17.MoveNext()
```

Comment: can you provide a stack trace for your exception?

Comment: Is there any `InnerException` ?

Comment: You are setting a `BaseAddress` for the HttpClient, so you should not specify the full address on the `GetAsync` method, only the relative path.

Comment: baseAddress exists, path right. This just for example

Comment: InnerException on gets on Russian)) 

Не удалось найти текст, связанный с этим кодом ошибки.
Не удается установить связь с сервером. Like Unable to establish connection with the server

Comment: Are you able to hit the same URL in a browser window?

Comment: In all browers works fine, except EDGE. It not open vagrant urls)